# Capture two strings in multi-line error message

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects, atom-editor

I have created a build package for [AtomBuilder](https://atombuild.github.io/) which I would like to extend to capture the file path and line number in which an error occurred. I have not been able to find a working RegEx pattern for this.

Here's what an error message commonly looks like:

```
Processing script file: "/Users/johndoe/Projects/test.nsi" (UTF8)
Invalid command: Foo
Error in script "/Users/johndoe/Projects/test.nsi" on line 5 -- aborting creation process
```

I'm really just after the the last line, since the amount of lines before that can differ, depending on the error. I need to capture the file path (Windows and Unix) between the quotes and the digit for the line number.

Here's what I have tried:

```
errorMatch: [
  '((.|\\n)*)Error in script "(?<file>[^"]+) on line (?<line>\\d+) -- aborting creation process'
]
```

Comment: That's not enough information. What have you tried? Why isn't it good enough?

Comment: You could try using a regex, something like /^Error.*"([^"]+)" on line (\d+)/ should do it - but you could supply a bit more info as idleberg suggests.

Comment: @Amit updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
const errorMatch = [
    '\\n(?<message>.+)\\nError in script "(?<file>[^"]+)" on line (?<line>\\d+) -- aborting creation process'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture groups `\1` and `\2` to obtain filepath and line no using following regex.

**Regex:** `Error.*"(.*)".*(\d+)`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO0tM8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try using capture groups to match parts that you need

```
var regex = /Error in script "(.*)" on line (\d+)/;

var match = message.match(regex);

if (match && match.length) {
  var filepath = match[1];
  var linenumber = match[2];

  console.log(filepath); // /Users/johndoe/Projects/test.nsi
  console.log(linenumber); //  5
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/moogs/zuodcsL7/**

**Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wU0aH4/1**

Comment: My problem is not the Regex itself, but getting it to work in AtomBuilder